# Deploying ReactJS app to GH-Pages renders blank page

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, manifest.json

[EDIT] solved

I'm trying to deploy my app on `gh-pages`.

**The problem**
When I visit the website I get a blank page and I can see the following error in the console : `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.` which I guess is the reason why I see a blank page.

My `manifest.json` file is the following one :

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "favicon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "favicon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

What is wrong in it and cause my app to display a blank page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `homepage:` in `packages.json` which wasn't correct